# How to format SQL Server time datatype with moment.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, time, momentjs

I want to be able to format the time data that i get from SQL server time datatype with moment.js what i get is "PS12H:30M" when i try to format that with moment.js i get "Invalid Date", can you please help me?

**Javascript**

```
moment("PS12H:30M").format('hh:mm A');
```

**Database**

```
[from]               TIME (1)     NOT NULL
[to]                 TIME (1)     NOT NULL
```

Comment: How did you get "PS12H:30M" out of a [SQL TIME data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)?  that's not one of the default string formats.

Comment: Well Matt i really don't know and most important it's non of my concern the guy who designed the database gave it to me that way am just the guy who's handling the presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse the String, since `"PS12H:30M"` isn't a recognized format.
Pass a parse String as the second parameter to moment, like this:

`moment("PS12H:30M", "HH:mm").format('hh:mm A');`

> `"12:30 PM"`